# Django: allow multiple accounts for a single profile

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I would like to enable multiple logins (credentials & permissions) for a single profile in my app.

Here is my current code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):

   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Ideally, I'd like the User model to have a ForeignKey to Profile, and that would be it. I could then have several Users for a same profile, and my problem would be solved.
Unfortunately I don't want to extend the User model because it's quite nasty, so I'd like to be able to put it in my Profile model.

ManyToManyField would work, but then the Users could have several profiles and that is not possible.

Do you have a clean, simple way to make some kind of "Reverse Foreign key" ?

Best,

Comment: Why is extending the User model so nasty? Seems a completely viable way of doing this... (that or creating another UserSharedProfile model that links to users and to profiles as a middleman)

Answer (score 0):

first of all extend the User model is not nasty . 
anyway you do not need to extend user model to do this job 
you just need a foreign key constraint to user model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING)
```

sharing model (table record) with several other User (table record) is a very common concept database developing.
if you have problem with your views.py then ask ask other question

```
user.profile_set
```

this is reverse access to all user have shared this profile 
see doc [following relationships backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: Unfortunately the admin doesn't recognize that and only allows me to chose one user in a dropdown instead of a multi dropdown.

Comment: let's say profile is a product and user is a customer . you sale the product to several customers . it is easy to reason about problem

Comment: I did exactly that, I added the user to the profile. Still, I want it the other way around.
I guess there's no other way than extending the user model then

Comment: This is why I don't want to do this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project